# UPDATE a column with middle bits masked with zeros

Tags: mysql, sql-update, concatenation, substr

SQL update column. want first 4 and last 2 digits rest all zeros in a number of x length.

i tried:

```
update mytable set mycol = 
CONCAT(substr(mycol,1,4) , substr('00000000',length(mycol)-6) , substr(mycol,-2));
```

this is ok if the column containing a 12 digit number but what if it's of some other length ?

In short i want:
123456789123 as 123400000023
1234567891234567 as 1234000000000067

Comment: What should happen if string length less than 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET mycol = 
    CONCAT(SUBSTR(mycol,1,4), REPEAT('0',LENGTH(mycol)-6), SUBSTR(mycol,-2))
```

This uses the [`REPEAT` function in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_repeat) to repeat '0' the specified number of times.

I've tested this with some sample data and it seems to do what you need, but you can test with your data by doing a `SELECT` like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(mycol,1,4), REPEAT('0',LENGTH(mycol)-6), SUBSTR(mycol,-2))
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update mytable set mycol = 
CONCAT(LEFT(mycol,4) , REPEAT('0',length(mycol)-6) , RIGHT(mycol,2));
```

With the LEFT and RIGHT functions you could specified length of strings from either side of the string. Repeat function will return a string with specified amount of '0' values.

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?